# What is the default move construct?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

What is the definition of the default move constructor? I can't think of anything sensible. Maybe a swap on ptr members and copy on values/reference member?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what the standard says (12.8/15):

> > The implicitly-defined copy/move constructor for a non-union class X performs a memberwise copy/move of its bases and members. [ Note: brace-or-equal-initializers of non-static data members are ignored. See also the example in 12.6.2. —end note ] The order of initialization is the same as the order of initialization of bases and members in a user-defined constructor (see 12.6.2). Let `x` be either the parameter of the constructor or, for the move constructor, an xvalue referring to the parameter. Each base or non-static data member is copied/moved in the manner appropriate to its type:
> >
> > — if the member is an array, each element is direct-initialized with the corresponding subobject of `x`;
> >
> > — if a member `m` has rvalue reference type `T&&`, it is direct-initialized with `static_cast<T&&>(x.m)`;
> >
> > — otherwise, the base or member is direct-initialized with the corresponding base or member of `x`.
> >
> > Virtual base class subobjects shall be initialized only once by the implicitly-defined copy/move constructor (see 12.6.2).

For pointers and fundamental types moving is the same as copying.

Answer (score 1):

Non-union members are moved in their initialization order, using the move semantics defined for each member type.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor

Comment: According to the link, int* should get a trivial move constructor, i.e. std::memmove. At least if it was a struct/class and not a built-in type.

Comment: @acidzombie24 I would bet it is a plain copy. That is probably the cheapest way of satisfying move semantics for built-in types.